# django + ajax post form

Tags: django, ajax

i tru use ajax with django.
There are 2 forms. the first with the name and mail. and a quick form with a confirmation code that comes in the mail.
views.py

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_code = generate_code(8)
        subject = 'code' 
        message = user_code
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],mail=request.POST['mail'])
            send_mail(subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[mail],fail_silently=False)                       
            return JsonResponse({ 'form1': render_to_string( 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': NameForm1()},request=request ) })
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})
```

template (detail.html)

```
    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="contact-form" >
   <h1>{%trans 'Registers' %}</h1>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.fio.label}} {{form.fio}}{{form.fio.help_text}}</div>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.phone.label}} {{form.phone}}{{form.phone.help_text}}</div>
   <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'send' %}" class="btn" id="btn">   
  </div>
</form>
```

I am hanging an event to submit this form

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: $this.serialize(), 
                success: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                    var parent=$("#my_form").parent();
                    parent.html(data.form1); 
                }, 
                error: function(data) 
                { console.log(data);
                    $this.html(data); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
});
```

ajax request works and get my 2 form (endreg.html)

```
    <form action="endreg/" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form2">
   {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="verification" >
 <div class="ver">
   {{form}}
     </div>
      <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'send' %}" class="btn1" > 
    </div>  
</form>
```

views.py

```
def endreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
            try:
                user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use)
                user.verification = True
                user.save() 
                JsonResponse({'message': 'thanks.'})
            except:
                JsonResponse({'error': 'erorr.'})
    else:
        form = NameForm1()
    return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': form})
```

and 2nd ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form2").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: $this.serialize(), 
                success: function(data) 
                { console.log(data);                                         
               }, 
                error: function(data) 
                { console.log(data);
                                } 
            }); 
        }); 
});
```

Now the question. why when I enter the code in the second form, the code is applied and a redirect to localhost:8000/endreg occurs with json .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your form is not valid, thats why it is loading the same page with the entered data. You should handle the failure condition for `form.is_valid()`. And also don't add the blank `exception` block for handling exceptions.

```
def endreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
            try:
                user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use)
                user.verification = True
                user.save() 
                messages.warning(request, u'thanks.')
            except Registration.DoesNotExist as e:  # Handling Exception for get()
                print("NOT FOUND", e)
                messages.warning(request, u'error.')
        else:  # if form is not valid
            messages.warning(request, u'not valid.')
            form = NameForm1() # reset the form
    else:
        form = NameForm1()
    return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': form})
```

In your HTML, you can render `{{ form.errors }}` as well.

Comment: when I enter the correct code I redirect to the endreg page and I see the form and the inscription thanks. how to remove the form